# Check for Control + Z

Tags: vb.net, winforms, visual-studio

How do I check if Control + Z is being pressed?
I managed to check for when one key is being pressed, but apparently I can't check for two at the same time.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Trap KeyDown event:

```
Private Sub Form1_KeyDown(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.Windows.Forms.KeyEventArgs) Handles MyBase.KeyDown
  If ((e.KeyCode = Keys.Z) AndAlso e.Control) Then
    (do what you need)
  End If
End Sub
```

Comment: I'd probably use `AndAlso` instead: `If e.Control AndAlso e.KeyCode = Keys.Z Then`

Comment: @Omega, @Scott: edited changing And to AndAlso. Thanks Scott.

Comment: Works beautifully. Thank you.